# how to assign value to django form's field before saving?

Tags: python, django-models, django-forms

if I have a model and form like this:

```
class Test(models.Model):
    name = Charfield()
    nickname = CharField()

class getNickname(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
    model = Test;
    exclude = ['nickname'];
```

the nickname will be a randomly generated name using a function.

```
def msms():
    return randomName;

def getNick(request):
    if request.method = 'POST':
        form = getNickname(request.POST);
        if form.is_valid():
            form.nickname = msms(); <--
            nickname = form.save();
```

when I called msms(), it gives me an error. what is the proper way of changing "nickname" using a function?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do it on the model.

```
    if form.is_valid():
        nickname = form.save(commit=False)
        nickname.nickname = msms()
        nickname.save()
```